# python fileinput if and

Tags: python, file-io

I want to find values in a line in a file and replace them.

When I do this:

```
def replace(file_name, name, original_value, new_value):
    for line in fileinput.input(file_name, inplace=1):
        if name in line:
            print(line)
```

I can print out each line that the 'name' appear in.

If I do the following then it DOES NOT print out the line even though the 2 values appear in the line in the file:

```
def replace(file_name, name, original_value, new_value):
    for line in fileinput.input(file_name, inplace=1):
        if name in line and original_value in line:
            print(line)
```

How do I get this to do IF AND?

```
//Sample line in my text file
add_argument('--look_for_this',  test)

config_name = "look_for_this"     
old = 'test'
new = 'new_value'

replace(config_file, config_name, old, new)
```

Comment: If you surround in brackets both conditions (separately), anything changes?

Comment: 'even though the 2 values appear in the line' ... would you mind adding the line as well as the values for name, original_value and new_value?

Comment: what you wrote is equivalent to `if (name in line) and (original_value in line):`, which is what you want, so i don't think we can reproduce this

Comment: Please see edit for values.  I added the () but it makes no difference.  When you say you cant reproduce this do you mean this cannot be done in python?

Comment: It means that you haven't described your problem clearly enough to get an answer (from me at least)

Comment: BTW there should be a better way to parse code/config files than this, your approach looks not clean

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code like the following and it works for me. You have to specify in more detail what the issue is!

```py
lines = ['1. a b c', '2. c d e', '3. e f g', '4. c e']
name = 'c'
original_value = 'e'

for line in lines:
    if name in line and original_value in line:
        print(line)
```

Producing the following output:

```
2. c d e
4. c e
```

Which is what you would expect. Hence, I can only assume that you must have some bug in the code which either provides the `name` or the `original_value` not in the form you expect. Or the line is not in the form you expect. E.g. encoding could be an issue if you look for specific byte patterns or similar.

Comment: hmmm interesting.  what could the difference be between using fileinput.input and your array method?

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: @HarryBoy: As @Lee points out, there should be no difference. And I actually tried it as well on my machine and it also works with fileinput. I could only explain it with either `name`, `original_value` or the file have a different encoding. If so the byte sequences of the relevant values are different and hence cannot be found.